# Problem re-installing ROS

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have removed ROS in order to solve some problems I had, but I removed the "ros" folder in /opt sending it to the trash, which I think was a bad idea.

I have tried to reinstall ROS again, but when I do
$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full

only the "stacks" folder is created inside /opt/electric.

I have done
$ sudo apt-get remove ros-electric-desktop-full
and tried to reinstall it again, but i doesn't work.

What should I do to get ROS again, please?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12762/problem-re-installing-ros/) by [BLaS](https://answers.ros.org/users/1491/blas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have already solved my problem.

I had to open Synaptic, look for ros-electric there, and mark for complete removal. Then I could reinstall it again.

---

Originally posted by [BLaS](https://answers.ros.org/users/1491/blas/) with karma: 56 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1